# Having trouble regarding matrix

Tags: matrices

How can I draw this matrix? since I’m new to LateX, it is very hard for me.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several environments for writing matrices with the `amsmath` package, including

- `matrix` for no delimiters
- `pmatrix` for parentheses as delimiters
- `bmatrix` for (square) brackets as delimiters
- `Bmatrix` for (curly) braces as delimiters
- `vmatrix` for `|` as delimiters
- `Vmatrix` for `||` as delimiters

Each of these environments has a starred variant that allows you to specify the alignment of entries in a column as an optional argument to the environment.

Once you've determined which matrix environment you want to use, you can then specify each row of your matrix, using ampersands to separate entries in a row and using double backslashes to separate rows.  This method of separating entries and rows is the same method used when writing tables in the `tabular` environment and similar.

This minimal working example should render your specific matrix as you need:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
    R = \begin{bmatrix}
        r_{11} & - & \ldots & \ldots & - \\
        r_{21} & r_{22} & \ldots & \ldots & r_{2N} \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ldots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        - & - & \ldots & \ldots & r_{MN}
    \end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the information and the example!

Comment: @Delan No problem!  Much of this information can also be found over in [the Wikibooks page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Matrices_and_arrays) for mathematics in LaTeX, and it provides a few examples too.